# gstreamer audio /video sync while encoding raw files(.yuv & .wav)

Tags: video, encoding, synchronization, gstreamer, pcm

I am trying to encode raw inputs (.yuv 420 and .wav ) using gstreamer
command line tool, but i am getting audio very late when compare to video.

Here is my command line

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe  -v filesrc location=Transformers1080p.wav
do-timestamp=true !  wavparse ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0
max-size-bytes=0 min-threshold-time=0000000000 !  audioconvert   !
audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, rate=44100, channels=2 !  voaacenc  ! mux.
filesrc location=Transformers1080p.yuv  !  videoparse  width=1920
height=1080 framerate=30/1 ! do-timestamp=true queue max-size-buffers = 0
max-size-time = 0 max-size-bytes = 0 min-threshold-time = 0 !  x264enc
bitrate=8000 !  queue  !  mpegtsmux name = mux ! filesink location=final.ts
```

Kindly guide my in right direction.

Notes:

- I have video input file "Transformers1080p.yuv" &
  audio input file "Transformers1080p.wav"
- codecs h264, aac
- output is .ts file.

Comment: I don't think these will fix your problem, but they're definitely wrong.  do-timestamp=true on a filesrc says to timestamp with the time that you read from the file, which has everything to do with how fast your disks are and nothing to do with audio/video sync.  Similarly, a queue with a max-size of 0 bytes/time is not being used correctly.

Comment: And also.. is it a constant offset or does the delay increase? Is the files really 30 fps?

Comment: thanks for replies..
yeah sure i will remove do-timestamp=true.. thanks for pointing out

.........I analyze the video codec properties .. it state its fps was 24 fps but i was giving 30 fps , so its was not in sync . 

just got it right .thanks all and .@Florian